# Setting up TeamCity on AWS Ec2

Tags: amazon-ec2, teamcity, build-agent

I have set up a Server and a BuildAgent on Amazon Ec2. I have configured the build agent to sit in the /home/ec2-user/build-agent directory (will this cause problems due to permissions?)
I then configured the build agent to point to the server through the public dns and port 8111. I have then started the build agent.

I used the Cloud Tab on the TC Web interface to setup the Build Agent on the server. I can see on the build agent host machine that a connection with the server has been established. Yet in the web interface I can see no build agents in either the unauthorized tab or the compatible tabs.

In short I cannot connect a build agent to the server?

Any help or ideas on this one would be greatly appreciated.

many thanks

Dermot

Comment: it seems like the agent config problem. please ensure the buildAgent.properties 's serverUrl is right, and agent server can access the url.